# When a Flash applet loses focus, how can I catch that event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, flash, events, focus

How do I get a JavaScript event when a Flash movie loses focus?

*eg.* like when the user clicks the HTML page.

Comment: Its not an "applet"! More like an "object" though you IT geeks can call it that if you wish.

Comment: @Jeremy: so rename it then... I almost put "movie" in to reflect the body of the question, but was looking for a way to differentiate between elements within the Flash, uh, object and those in the surrounding HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant remember off hand if divs support onFocus and onBlur, but you could try making one div absolutely positioned to the top left where the width = the body width and the height = the body height, then put another one on top of it which only covers the object in question, then set an action to the big one's onFocus. Probably wont work, it was just my first thought.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the general answer, but if your flash is just diplaying things, no user interaction... try adding a hidden textfield and give the focus to it. Then you can check for that blur event.